# How to create SharePoint 2010's site column through Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was trying to create lists, content type and site columns through Visual Studio 2010. There were options of adding content type and list instance but not of content type. So, I could not figure out how to add site column? What item do I need to add for this and what kind of coding is to be done for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this resources may help you:
Walkthrough: Create a Site Column, Content Type, and List for SharePoint => http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx
You may also try SharePoint Designer 2010 instead of Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAML but I wouldn't recommend it. The better way is using object model and feature event receiver.  An complete example is quite long, here is the link http://zhouyupublic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/create-site-column-and-content-type.html.My

My recent favorite way to do the same is using PowerShell. But since you ask about how to do it with VS, it is outside the topic here.